# How can I obtain the distribution of the number of customers in a non-starionary MM1 queue given an interval partition of stationary transitions?

Tags: probability, distributions, forecasting, markov-process, queueing

I am considering this [transient solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue#Transient_solution) for the probability mass function over the number of "customers" in an MM1 queue:

$$ p(k; t, i, \lambda, \mu) =\\ \exp \left( - (\lambda + \mu) t \right) \left[ \rho^{\frac{k-i}{2}} I_{k-i}(at) + \rho^{\frac{k-i-1}{2}} I_{k+i+1}(at) + (1 - \rho) \rho \sum_{j=k+i+2}^{\infty} \rho^{\frac{-j}{2}} I_{j}(at) \right] \tag{1}$$

where

- $\lambda$ is the arrival rate
- $\mu$ is the service rate
- $t$ is time
- $\rho := \frac{\lambda}{\mu}$
- $a := 2 \sqrt{\lambda \mu}$
- $I_{\bullet}(\bullet)$ is the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1)

Since a [MM1 queue is a continuous time Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue#Model_definition) I figure that I could rely on the Markov property to generalize somewhat. The purpose of this generalization is to predict probabilities without performing multiple runs of [discrete-event simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-event_simulation). A possible application is distribution forecasts where the day-of-year or day-of-week effects are forecasted and the only sources of non-stationarity.

Suppose $t \in T = [0, \tau]$ is assigned an [interval partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval) such that for every element of the partition designated by a time $\tau_h$ we assign $\lambda_{\tau_h}$ and $\mu_{\tau_h}$.

For a given interval $T_{\tau_{h}} := [\tau_{h-1}, \tau_{h}]$ of the partition equation (1) holds in for inputs $p(k_t; t, k_{\tau_{h-1}}, \lambda_{\tau_h}, \mu_{\tau_h})$ provided that $t \in T_{\tau_{h}}$.

My intuition is that this new process is also a Markov process conditioned on $k_0$. My hope is some functional using (1) would do the trick.

How can I obtain the distribution of the number of customers in a non-starionary MM1 queue given an interval partition of stationary transitions??

Comment: @Ben I suspect you are especially equipped to provide feedback on this question, if not answer it.

Comment: Algorithmically I think I can sample using $(1)$ at the endpoints of the intervals until I reach the largest $\tau_h \leq t$, then sample within that interval as per $(1)$ at $t$. The desired distribution may be equal to the result of [integrating out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) all but the last distribution to account for different paths.

Comment: Might also want to consider [phase-type distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-type_distribution).